# Modal Angular 2 styling div inside body

Tags: css, typescript, angular, modal-dialog

How can I style a div inside of the body of a bootstrap modal?
this is my model:

```
<div> <button class="btn btn-danger" (click)="modal.alert()
    .title('Model')
    .body('<div id='Mytext'> text </div>')
    .okBtn('ok')
    .open();">Open Model</button> </div>
```

My css:

```
@Mytext{
 color:red;
}
```

It doesn't work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand your code standerd, but yes we can simply put you css in your code and color works fine like this -

```
<p id="myText">Demo Text</p>
 ....
#myText{
    color:red;
  }
```

here is the example <kbd>[Working Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/GhnCHy3jUKB6LLZDlhrp)</kbd>

PS: -

- ID in css is represented by `#` not by `@`.

Comment: your welcome @SamuelRibeiro ,  you can mark as accepted if you got your answer, also can upvote if you learn something new by this answer.